# Two questions of the measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> (1) Suppose the function $g(x) = \sqrt{|f(x)|}$ is measurable on $[0,1]$ with respect to  classical Lebesgue measure. Does it follow that the function $f(x)$ is measurable on $[0,1]$?
>
> (2) And if $f$ is integrable on Lebesgue in $[0,1]$, then what can you say about the function $g$ ?

I don't know answer to (1), but I think that in (2) can be a counterexample to the fact that this is wrong.

I would be very grateful if you helped me.

Answer (score 3):

1. Consider a non-measurable function $f$ such that $f(x)\in\{-1,1\}$ for all $x$ (take $S$ non measurable and $f=\chi_S-\chi_{S^c}$).
2. Notice that $\sqrt{|f(x)|}\leqslant |f(x)|+1$.

Comment: 1. $S = [0,1]$ ?

Comment: No, this set _is_ measurable. The existence of non-measurable sets is non-trivial. It has been discussed previously on this website.

Comment: 2. Function $|f(x)|$ is integrable, then $|f(x) + 1|$ is integrable and $\sqrt{|f(x)|}$ integrable by inequality. Is it correct?

Comment: It's almost correct: use instead integrability of $|f|+1$. (but you got the idea).